# Average Current for switched circuit

Tags: current

I'm looking to confirm I have the correct process to determine an average current for the following switched circuit:
I peak is given as 10A
I rms is given as 1.8 A. From: $$Irms = Ipk\sqrt{D}$$ I get a duty cycle of 0.0324, which then results in 0.324 A as the average current. Is this correct?

Comment: What switched circuit? Is this question missing a schematic or picture?

Comment: no schematic, just a general process clarification. If the current is 10A DC for example being switched such that 1.8rms results, does this duty cycle and average make sense? ie have I calculated it with the correct understanding that I use the given equation to find the DC then multipley that by the peak to get the average.

Comment: Depends what you're trying to do. I've taken a guess at what the circuit might be in my answer. I hope that helps. When you say "the following switched circuit", I was expecting to see a switched circuit. There are many different switched circuits.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I initially had "the following:" and edited just before posting to add the switching text in the attempt to be clear about the duty cycle, but then failed to proof read it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your maths looks fine, but in order to know whether it is correct or not we'd need to know the shape of the wave. Your equation is true for a simple uni-polar pulse waveform, so I'll start there.

Suppose we had the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4RTHO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And `SW1` was closed with duty 0.0324 = 3.24%. We'd get a waveform like this:

[image]

Then \$I_{peak}\$ is clearly 10A. \$I_{rms}\$ is always given by this equation:

\$I_{rms} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} i(t)^2 dt}\$

The integral for most of the 1 second period is zero. For the brief on time (0.0324 seconds) \$i(t)\$ is 10, so the integral reduces to:

\$I_{rms} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1}\int_{0}^{0.0324} 10^2 dt} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1}100\times0.0324} = \sqrt{3.24} = 1.8\$

which checks out pretty nicely.

\$I_{average}\$, on the other hand is always given by this equation:

\$I_{average} = \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} i(t) dt\$

This integral reduces to:

\$I_{average} = \frac{1}{1}\int_{0}^{0.0324} 10 dt = \frac{1}{1}10\times0.0324 = 0.324\$

So, for a uni-polar pulse waveform I'd say yep, your maths looks right. For any other waveform, all bets are off.